# Error: Compile Error: Condition expression must be of type Boolean at line 8 column 9

Tags: apex, compile-error

**Error**

> Error: Compile Error: Condition expression must be of type Boolean at line 8 column 9

**Class**

```
public class DataenteringVF2 {
    public string name      {set;get;}
    public string lastName  {set;get;}
    public string firstName {set;get;}
    public decimal salary   {set;get;}
    public integer age      {set;get;}
    public void EmployeeDetails(){
        if (name='bhargav'){
            salary=20000;
            age=20;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use double equals (`==`) for comparison:

**Works**

```
if (name == 'some value')
```

**Fails**

```
if (name = 'some value')
```

Have a look at [Understanding Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm):

> **Operator**
>   `==`
>
> **Syntax**
>   `x == y`
>
> **Description**
>   Equality operator. If the value of x equals the value of y, the expression evaluates to true. Otherwise, the expression evaluates to false.
>
> Note:
>
> - Unlike Java, == in Apex compares object value equality, not reference equality, except for user-defined types. Consequently:
>
>   - String comparison using == is case-insensitive
>   - ID comparison using == is case-sensitive, and does not distinguish between 15-character and 18-character formats
>   - User-defined types are compared by reference, which means that two objects are equal only if they reference the same location in memory.
>       You can override this default comparison behavior by providing equals
>       and hashCode methods in your class to compare object values instead.
> - For sObjects and sObject arrays, == performs a deep check of all sObject field values before returning its result. Likewise for
>     collections and built-in Apex objects.
> - For records, every field must have the same value for == to evaluate to true. x or y can be the literal null.
> - The comparison of any two values can never result in null.
> - SOQL and SOSL use = for their equality operator, and not ==. Although Apex and - SOQL and SOSL are strongly linked, this
>     unfortunate syntax discrepancy exists because most modern languages
>     use = for assignment and == for equality. The designers of Apex deemed
>     it more valuable to maintain this paradigm than to force developers to
>     learn a new assignment operator. The result is that Apex developers
>     must use == for equality tests in the main body of the Apex code, and
>     = for equality in SOQL and SOSL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Condition expression must be of type Boolean. 
In this code, you used single equal Assignment Operator `=` expression on line 8. This expression not type of Boolean only for assign values from right side Operands to left side Operands. You should use `==` condition expression (Relational Operator) of type Boolean. It is use for compare two objects based on memory reference.

```
If(name=='bhargav'){
    Salary=20000;
    age=20;
}
```